# Get returning value of a function in Inno setup

Tags: delphi, inno-setup

i need to write in registry the current date, when my app were installed. For this i have created function in [code] section and trying to call it from [registry] section but it doesnt work. How can i call my function from [registry] section to get the value which it returns?

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\MyAppName; ValueType: string; ValueName: date; ValueData: **{code:DateTime}**; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist; Tasks: ; Languages: 
[Code]
function DateTime() : String;
begin
  result := GetDateTimeString('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss', '-', ':');
end;
```

Comment: i had updated the question, check it please!

Comment: +1 Wow! I didn't know you could make a function call from the [Registry] section in Inno. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare the function with a string parameter

```
function DateTime(param: string) : String;
```

even if it is not used inside the function.

The *{code:* call allows one string parameter. If you omit it (like you did), an empty string is used.